# How to place a text between two straight line android?

Tags: android, textview

I need to place a text between a straight line. I tried by using view but textview comes below the line. How to solve this?
My code is as follows:

```
   <RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

 >
<View

         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="2dp"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/orText"
         android:background="#c0c0c0"/>
 <View
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="2dp"
         android:background="#c0c0c0"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/orText"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/orText"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:text="OR"
     android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is screenshot,

[image]

Comment: You could use a **9 patch** as your TextView's background.

Comment: @DerGolem +1, that would actually be not only the easiest, but much more efficient solution as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/orText"
            android:background="#c0c0c0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="OR"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/orText"
            android:background="#c0c0c0" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]