# creating custom view is needing for android

Tags: android

I want to create custom view as below.

---------- OR ---------

Line + 'Phrase' + Line

Which is a correct way to do it?
Relative layout, Grid, or what?
please advise

Comment: what is "OR"? what is "Line"?

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293827/how-to-place-a-text-between-two-straight-line-android)

Comment: @noev, on dublicate answer is using relativelayout. But our friend Chirag Savsani is using LinearLayout. Which is a correct answer.Both answers works correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for view.

This will adjust according to your screen width.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="#D0D0D0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Your text goes here" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="#D0D0D0" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: noew said it is dublicate. yes it is really dublicate. Sorry for it. But in dublicate question answer is relative layout but in yours one linearLayput. Which to use? Please advise